# Passing value to a form input field inside a jquery dialogbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, dialog, leaflet

I have a map on my index page. I want to click on the map and place a marker on the position. The click event has a function where i want to open up a modal (jquery dialog box) and load a form from another child html page with the position now filled in the right form-field.

My problem is passing the value (the marker position) to the input field in the form. My function seems to work if i put the input field somewhere on the index page but not in the child template in the dialogbox.

I'm trying with this **$('#test_input').val(lng + ',' + lat);** But it only show the value for millisecond then disappears. Do you have any ideas why this isn't working? Or how to reconstruct this? Thanks!

```
function onMapClick(e) {
      var lat = e.latlng.lat;
      var lng = e.latlng.lng;

      if (typeof marker != 'undefined') {
          map.removeLayer(marker);  
          marker = L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: redMarker}).addTo(map);
      }
      else {
          marker = L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: redMarker}).addTo(map); 
      }


      $('#upload-modal').load('upload/ #myform');

      $('#test_input').val(lng + ',' + lat);  //This is what I'm trying<---------- 

        $('#upload-modal').dialog({
              height: 550,
              width: 500,
              modal: false,
              buttons: {
                    Upload: function() { 
                        var dialog = $(this), 
                            form = $('#myform'),
                            data = form.serialize();

                    $('.off').remove(); 

                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: 'upload/',
                        data: data,
                        type: 'post',

                        success: function(response) {
                            res = $.parseJSON(response);

                            if (res['status'] == 'OK') {
                                alert('Thank you! Form has been submitted'); 
                                dialog.dialog('close'); 
                            }

                            else if (res['status'] == 'bad') {
                                delete res['status'] 
                                var errors = res; 

                                $.each(errors, function(key, value) {

                                    var err = $('<span></span>', {
                                                    'class': 'off',
                                                    'text': value
                                            }),
                                        br = $('<br></br>', {
                                            'class': 'off',
                                        }),
                                        input = $('#id_'+key).parent(); 

                                    br.appendTo(input);

                                    err.appendTo(input);

                                    err.css('color', 'red').css('font-size', '10px');

                                });
                            }
                        }

                      });

                    }
                  }
            });       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `#test_input` is in your form so you have to wait until the other form is completely loaded, use a callback like this:

```
$('#upload-modal').load('upload/ #myform', function(){
    $('#test_input').val(lng + ',' + lat);
});
```